# fadeOut a prepend div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've prepended a div like

```
<div id="p">
 lol
</div>
```

with `$("#stream").prepend("<div id="p">lol</div>");` and then, when i click on a button, i wanna fadeOut it. `$("#p").fadeOut();` doesn't work, how to fix it?!

The prepend it's because of an ajax post call, i prepend the response of the php (it insert mysql into the db and show the div with the post) but i can't delete it. also OnHover for opacity doesn't work D:

EDIT: it was a problem with ajax, sry

Comment: Can you post your code as you have it?

Comment: You should make a jsfiddle when you ask Javascript or jQuery questions.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$("#stream").prepend("<div id=\"p\">y so serious</div>");

$("#btn").click(function(){

$("#p").fadeOut('slow');
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LZxRd/5/

Comment: You don't need the 'div' part of the `$("div#stream")` selector since you're searching for an ID. This actually SIGNIFICANTLY slows the selector down - http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-with-out-tagname.

Comment: @Scottie you are right but i think i misunderstood the question so changed it ...

Answer (score 3):

Are you escaping the quote marks?

```
"<div id=\"p\">lol</div>"
```

Comment: You could also nest single and double quotes: `"<div id='p'>lol</div>"`